# prevent windows from sending destination port unreachable when getting ping reply

Tags: c#, .net, pcap.net

I have implemented a ping request with pcap.net. Everything is working fine but when the destination replies with a icmp echo response windows immediatly sends an icmp destination port unreachable.

```
me        other host
|           |
|---------->| Ping using pcap.net to send
|           |
|<----------| Ping-reply
|           |
|---------->| icmp Port unreachable
```

How can i prevent windows from doing this?

Comment: So the packet looks (to windows) like an invalid response right?  Is this just as simple as disallowing incoming ping/ICMP altogether in your windows firewall?  (note: winpcap will emit packets, but I don't think it usually blocks them)

Comment: you are right. pcap can't block packets

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should just be able to turn that packet off in Windows:

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms912869

In Windows Firewall settings:

> Allow outgoing destination unreachable
>
> Data sent over the Internet that fails to reach this computer due to
>   an error will be discarded and acknowledged with a "destination
>   unreachable" message explaining the failure.

Comment: i will test it soon when i have the time